# Populating SQLite ListViews Dynamically in Real-time, Between Activities, Using onListItemClicks/intents/other?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I'm fairly new to Android, and would really like to get the basic user flow of my app accounted for, so I can get a sense of accomplishment that will keep me interested enough to work on all areas of it. I know this probably isn't the best practice, but I will go back later and make sure I have multi-threading, singleton DB, Async, and all the other good stuff. Mainly I want to get to the UI designing part ASAP.

Basically, I'm trying to update the SQL queries based upon onListItemClicks, and dynamically with user navigation, through authors, keywords, categories, etc.

I have this working, and thought for sure there would be a way to make something work as it corresponds with the DB quite easily, but I've yet to find anything:

> ```
> @Override
> ```
>
> protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
> Log.i("FragmentList", "authors_id " + id);

Here's some other code I've tried, but failed with:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){}
```

---

```
String selectedItem = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String query = "SELECT body FROM \"main\".\"quotes\" WHERE _id = '" + selectedItem + "'";
```

I've also tried a huge number of different intent/bundle methods

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

I was able to get a couple of intents to pass values across activities, but I kept getting null values and inconsistent results.

[image: Screenshot with a list of results]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, authorlistactivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    bundle.putLong("id", id);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

add this part to your next activity's on create method:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    assert bundle != null;
    int position = bundle.getInt("position");
    long id = bundle.getLong("id");
```

Apparently querying is a lot more lax than I thought it was, as demonstrated by vogella:

```
        // Database creation SQL statement
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
                + TABLE_TODO
                + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_SUMMARY + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION
                + " text not null"
                + ");";
```

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html